# XCode выдает ошибку "The file could not be unlocked"

Tags: xcode, mac

При попытке сохранить или редактировать выдает ошибку "The file could not be unlocked. Unlocking failed for an unknown reason." Пробовал открыть доступ через свойства, тот же итог. Что это и как с этим справиться?